# DBCC checkDB stuck in killed/rollback state

Tags: sql-server

I killed DBCC CheckDB Job of 3TB Database which has been rolling back since 17 hours with 89 %.as i have checked that the SPID running with waittype EXECSYNC.
Could we have any other way to clear this mess without restarting SQL Server

Comment: Oh dear. Why did you kill it?

Comment: Developer  was requested for  kill  this  process, so  I  did it

Comment: Why do you think a restart will fix your “issue”?

Comment: RE:VTC, not sure how this is off-topic, voting to leave open

Comment: Unfortunately I have  restarted sql services and  luckily nothing bad  happened,  server and  databases  are healthy and  online ...

Answer (score 1):

Restarting a server while something is rolling back, is almost always a bad idea. You may make things worse.

You don't say if you are using one of the repair options with [DBCC CHECKDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you are, it can complicate things even more.

It has been a few hours since the original question was posted, so things have probably either self corrected or gotten worse.  Hopefully you have backups, that you will be able to use in the recovery, if things are not going well.

Some Related posts that may help

- [Why did a SQL Server Restart roll-back seemingly committed transactions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/174340/21924)
- [SQL database stuck in recovery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/250903/21924)
- [KILLED/ROLLBACK query doesn't stop running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/142218/21924)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2 - Service shutdown - what with running stored procedures?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/173677/21924)
- [Query Execution Time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11246/21924)

Comment: Great help thank you

Answer (score 1):

See Paul Randall's comments on DBCC CHECKDB.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-curious-case-of-unstoppable-dbcc-checkdb/